# BreezeJS editing data not working

Tags: breeze

I was able to follow the instruction on adding data, that part was easy and understandable. But when I tried to follow instructions for editing data, I'm completely lost.

I am following the todo sample, which works quite well, but when I tried to add to my own project using the same principle, nothing works.

in my controller, I have the following:

```
function listenForPropertyChanged() {
    // Listen for property change of ANY entity so we can (optionally) save
    var token = dataservice.addPropertyChangeHandler(propertyChanged);

    // Arrange to remove the handler when the controller is destroyed
    // which won't happen in this app but would in a multi-page app
    $scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
        dataservice.removePropertyChangeHandler(token);
    });

    function propertyChanged(changeArgs) {
        // propertyChanged triggers save attempt UNLESS the property is the 'Id'
        // because THEN the change is actually the post-save Id-fixup 
        // rather than user data entry so there is actually nothing to save.
        if (changeArgs.args.propertyName !== 'Id') { save(); }
    }
}
```

The problem is that any time I change a control on the view, the propertyChanged callback function never gets called.

Here's the code from the service:

```
function addPropertyChangeHandler(handler) {
    // Actually adds any 'entityChanged' event handler
    // call handler when an entity property of any entity changes
    return manager.entityChanged.subscribe(function (changeArgs) {
        var action = changeArgs.entityAction;
        if (action === breeze.EntityAction.PropertyChange) {
            handler(changeArgs);
        }
    });
}
```

If I put a break point on the line:

```
var action = changeArgs.entityAction;
```

In my project, it never reaches there; in the todo sample, it does! It completely skips the whole thing and just loads the view afterwards. So none of my callback functions work at all; so really, nothing is subscribed.

Because of this, when I try to save changes, the manager.hasChanges() is always false and nothing happens in the database.

I've been trying for at least 3 days getting this to work, and I'm completely dumbfounded by how complicated this whole issue has been for me.

Note: I'm using JohnPapa's HotTowel template. I tried to follow the Todo editing functionality to a Tee.. and nothing is working the way I'd like it to.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole time I thought the problem was in the javascript client side end of things. Turned out that editing doesn't work when you created projected DTOs.

So in my server side, I created a query:

```
public IQueryable<PersonDTO> getPerson(){
     return (from _person in ContextProvider.Context.Queries
            select new PersonDTO
            {
                Id = _person.Id,
                FirstName = _person.FirstName,
                LastName = _person.LastName
            }).AsQueryable();
}
```

Which just projected a DTO to send off to the client. This did work with my app in fetching data and populating things. So this is NOT wrong. Using this, I was able to add items and fetch items, but there's no information that allowed the entitymanager to know about the item. When I created an item, the entitymanager has a "createEntity" which allowed me to tell the entitymanager which item to use.. in my case:

```
manager.createEntity(person, initializeValues);
```

Maybe if there was a "manager.getEntity" maybe that would help?

Anyways, I changed the above query to get it straight from the source:

```
public IQueryable<Person> getPeople(){
    return ContextProvider.Context.People;
}
```

Note ContextProvider is:

```
readonly EFContextProvider<PeopleEntities> ContextProvider = 
    new EFContextProvider<PeopleEntities>();
```

So the subscribe method in the javascript checks out the info that's retrieved straight from the contextual object.. interesting. Just wish I didn't spend 4 days on this.